# Need to sleep for TestScheduler to finish

Tags: rx-swift

#### Summary

I create an Observable that emits events by calling `onNext` from a `DispatchQueue.async`, and my corresponding unit test needs to `sleep(...)` in order to actually receive the events, even though I use the `TestScheduler`.

#### Detailed question

I create the following `Observable`, which reads events from a gRPC stream. I believe that gRPC is not so important here: just note that I `call.receive()` in a `while` loop, and feed that to `onNext`.

```swift
private func createPositionObservable() -> Observable<Position> {
    return Observable.create { observer in
        let request = DronecodeSdk_Rpc_Telemetry_SubscribePositionRequest()

        do {
            let call = try self.service.subscribePosition(request, completion: { (callResult) in
                if callResult.statusCode == .ok || callResult.statusCode == .cancelled {
                    observer.onCompleted()
                } else {
                    observer.onError(RuntimeTelemetryError(callResult.statusMessage!))
                }   
            })  

            DispatchQueue.init(label: "DronecodePositionReceiver").async {
                while let responseOptional = try? call.receive(), let response = responseOptional {
                    observer.onNext(Position.translateFromRpc(response.position))
                }   
            }   

            return Disposables.create {
                call.cancel()
            }   
        } catch {
            observer.onError(error)
            return Disposables.create()
        }   
    }   
    .subscribeOn(scheduler)
}
```

I now try to test this code with the function below. Again, the first paragraph is only about setting the gRPC context. What I believe is important is that:

1. I use a `TestScheduler`
2. I pass this scheduler to gRPC (`scheduler` is passed to `Telemetry`, and is used as `subscribeOn(scheduler)` above)
3. I `sleep(2)` before the asserts

```swift
func checkPositionObservableReceivesEvents(positions: [DronecodeSdk_Rpc_Telemetry_Position]) {
    let fakeService = DronecodeSdk_Rpc_Telemetry_TelemetryServiceServiceTestStub()
    let fakeCall = DronecodeSdk_Rpc_Telemetry_TelemetryServiceSubscribePositionCallTestStub()
    fakeCall.outputs.append(contentsOf: positions.map{ position in createPositionResponse(position: position) })
    fakeService.subscribePositionCalls.append(fakeCall)
    let expectedEvents = positions.map{ position in next(1, translateRPCPosition(positionRPC: position)) }

    let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
    let observer = scheduler.createObserver(Telemetry.Position.self)
    let telemetry = Telemetry(service: fakeService, scheduler: scheduler)

    let _ = telemetry.position.subscribe(observer)
    scheduler.start()

    sleep(2)

    XCTAssertEqual(expectedEvents.count, observer.events.count)
    XCTAssertTrue(observer.events.elementsEqual(expectedEvents, by: { (observed, expected) in
        observed.value == expected.value
    })) 
}
```

If I don't `sleep(...)`, my asserts fail and `observer.events.count` receives no event. It feels like the assert happens before the events are emitted.

How should I deal with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You deal with that by not creating a DispatchQueue inside your `create` function. Instead the function needs to accept a Scheduler as a parameter and you use the scheduler to create the async block.

Then in your test, you pass in the test scheduler.

Something like this will do it:

```
let disposable = self.scheduler.schedule(0, action: { _ in
    var cancel = false
    while let responseOptional = try? call.receive(), let response = responseOptional, cancel == false {
        observer.onNext(Position.translateFromRpc(response.position))
    }
    return Disposables.create { cancel = true }
})

return Disposables.create {
    disposable.dispose()
    call.cancel()
}
```

Comment: So you mean that I can use `scheduler` (the one that I use in `.subscribeOn(scheduler)` above) to create an async block? I have seen `schedulePeriodic` (but I don't want to specify a time interval), `schedule` (but that runs it only once), `scheduleRecursive` (I don't feel like I need recursivity here) and `scheduleRelative` (which is the same as `schedule` but with a due time).